# jQuery sorting table Columns basis row heading selected

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table

I want to sort my table columns basis the row heading selected. I'm trying to adapt the code used in the following fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/fKMqD/) to work for this:

The table has 2 rows with the row-heading 'Ranking' & 'Rating'. A 'Sort By' button to select by which parameter to sort:

```
Sort by: <select id="SortBy">
    <option></option>
    <option>Ranking</option>
    <option>Rating</option>
</select>
```

The jquery to call-upon the sort function is as follows:

```
jQuery("#SortBy").on('change', function () {
        var Rows = $('.CompTable > tr');

        var RowtoSort = $(".CompTable > tr." + $(this).find("option:selected").text());

        RowtoSort.find('td:not(:first)').sort(function(a, b) {
            return a-b
        }).each(function(new_Index) {

        var original_Index = $(this).index();

        '.CompTable > thead > tr > th'.each(function() {
        var th = $(this).find('th:not(:first)');
        console.log(th);
        if (original_Index !== new_Index)
        th.eq(original_Index).insertAfter(th.eq(new_Index));
        });

        '.compTable > tbody > tr > td'.each(function() {
        var td = $(this).find('td:not(:first)');
        console.log(td);
        if (original_Index !== new_Index)
        td.eq(original_Index).insertAfter(td.eq(new_Index));
        });

        });
        return false;
        });

    });
```

But for some reason, the table columns is not getting sorted as they are supposed to. Have tried to rework it in multiple ways but to no avail.

Following is the complete code that I'm working with:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  jQuery("#SortBy").on('change', function() {
    var Rows = $('.CompTable > tr');

    var RowtoSort = $(".CompTable > tr." + $(this).find("option:selected").text());

    RowtoSort.find('td:not(:first)').sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b
    }).each(function(new_Index) {

      var original_Index = $(this).index();

      '.CompTable > thead > tr > th'.each(function() {
        var th = $(this).find('th:not(:first)');
        console.log(th);
        if (original_Index !== new_Index)
          th.eq(original_Index).insertAfter(th.eq(new_Index));
      });

      '.compTable > tbody > tr > td'.each(function() {
        var td = $(this).find('td:not(:first)');
        console.log(td);
        if (original_Index !== new_Index)
          td.eq(original_Index).insertAfter(td.eq(new_Index));
      });

    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.CompTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Sort by:
<select id="SortBy">
  <option></option>
  <option>Ranking</option>
  <option>Rating</option>
</select>

<table class="CompTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Samsung</th>
      <th>LG</th>
      <th>Apple</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Ranking">
      <td>Ranking</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Rating">
      <td>Rating</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td>5.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also find the js-fiddle for the same:https://jsfiddle.net/mithunu/59d8gkry/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo

```js
$("#SortBy").on('change', function() {

  var Rows = $('.CompTable tr');
  var RowtoSort = $(".CompTable tr." + $(this).find("option:selected").text());

  RowtoSort.find('td:not(:first)').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text())
  }).each(function(new_Index) {
    var original_Index = $(this).index();

    Rows.each(function() {
      var td = $(this).find('td, th');
      if (original_Index !== new_Index)
        td.eq(original_Index).insertAfter(td.eq(new_Index));
    });    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.CompTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Sort by:
<select id="SortBy">
  <option></option>
  <option>Ranking</option>
  <option>Rating</option>
</select>

<table class="CompTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Samsung</th>
      <th>LG</th>
      <th>Apple</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Ranking">
      <td>Ranking</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Rating">
      <td>Rating</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td>5.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```